# Drupal 8 API REST login works on curl but not postman

Tags: rest, drupal, postman, drupal-8

I have a bizarre issue with Drupal's REST API that I can't work out.

The exact same POST to /user/login?_format=json does NOT work in Postman (error 403 Forbidden) but with same parameters it works correctly in CURL.

This Curl works:
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST   --data '{"name":"bobo", "pass":"xxx"}' http://[domain]/user/login?_format=json

I get back json with the uid, name, a csrf token, logout token and any roles.

Now in Postman, I select Post, my url is "http://[domain]/user/login?_format=json" for header i select 'Content-Type' and value 'application/json' and paste the {"name":"bobo", "pass":"xxx"} section into 'raw' under body.

Now I get 403 Forbidden and response: {"message":""}

Is there a setting in Postman I'm missing or is this a bug somewhere?? It seems utterly bizarre to me.

Comment: finding out with more testing that it works the first time in Postman, and returns a cookie;  ONLY if I delete the cookie will the request work

Comment: however it still doesn't work from a javascript api that is NOT sending a cookie (from iOS); still get 403, what is wrong with this endpoint? Can I make it public somewhere??

Answer (score 4):

Actually, all is correct here.

User should be logged out to access `/user/login` endpoint (check [user.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.routing.yml/8.3.x)). Unlike curl, Postman behaves as a browser, i.e. saves all session cookies, so you are just logged in after first call and can't anymore access login endpoint. You may call `/user/logout` after logging in to be able to call it again.

Thus, I think your code works properly :)

Comment: It's true what @stanislav-agapov  Stanislav Agapov says, I just tried it, now a question for Stanislav Agapov.

I logged in as normal by the browser as user admin, enable the block that shows the connected users. Then by postmal login with another username and the server response was correct, I went to the browser as user and after cleaning the cache appear the two users as connected. Then in postman close the session of the other user, but in the block even cleaning chache still appears the user from which closed session.

What can be the reason?